# Arabic characters not showing on Android React native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-studio

I have react native application that fetch some text data via api the response is represent as json .. the point is i have no issue with IOS the words showing correctly but on android nothing is showing.

Any suggestion for these kind of issues ?

The code below that i use to fetch api response

```
async UNSAFE_componentWillMount(){
const searchUrl = (config.BASE_URL+'/get_packges_info'+this.props.locale,'get')
console.log(searchUrl)
console.log('#######################################$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$')

await fetch(searchUrl).then(res=> res.json()).then(response=>{
  console.log(response.data.images.length)
  response.data.images.map(item=>{
  })
  this.setState({images_data: response.data})
});
```

}

Comment: Please, provide minimal code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Tarik i attached the code to fetch the api response ... it is odd that working normally on IOS just on android devices i have that issue

Comment: When you log, do you see anything in the log?

Comment: @Tarik, Thank you dear i had something wrong in the code , the issue fixed

Comment: You may answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed by delete the condition below form my code

```
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
   text = text.replace(/\r?\n/g, '').replace(/[\u0080-\uFFFF]/g, '');
 }
```